# Can't dismiss dialog in Android

Tags: java, android, android-dialog

I don't know why my dialog can not be dismissed. Actually, I see in my database, the data we take successfully gets saved in that database. Just the dialog dismiss code is not working.

**This is my code:**

```
package com.app.kfstore.EmailLoginRegister;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.app.kfstore.MainActivity;
import com.app.kfstore.OperationRetrofitApi.ApiClient;
import com.app.kfstore.OperationRetrofitApi.ApiInterface;
import com.app.kfstore.OperationRetrofitApi.Users;
import com.app.kfstore.R;
import com.blogspot.atifsoftwares.animatoolib.Animatoo;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class EmailRegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText name,email,password;
    private Button regBtn;
    public static ApiInterface apiInterface;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_email_register);

        //////hide status bar code//////
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        //////end code for hide status bar//////

        apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

        init();

    }

    private void init() {

        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        regBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        regBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Registration();

            }
        });

    }

    private void Registration() {

        String user_name = name.getText().toString().trim();
        String user_email = email.getText().toString().trim();
        String user_password = password.getText().toString().trim();

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(user_name)){
            name.setError("Name is required!");
        }

        else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(user_email)){
            email.setError("Email is required!");
        }

        else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(user_password)){
            password.setError("Password is required!");
        }

        else {
            ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            dialog.setTitle("Registering...");
            dialog.setMessage("Please wait while we adding your credentials");
            dialog.show();
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

            Call<Users> call = apiInterface.performEmailRegistration(user_name,user_email,user_password);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<Users>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Users> call, Response<Users> response) {
                    if(response.body().getResponse().equals("ok")){
                        Toast.makeText(EmailRegisterActivity.this, "Your account has been created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }

                    else if(response.body().getResponse().equals("failed!")){
                        Toast.makeText(EmailRegisterActivity.this, "Something went wrong, Please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }

                    else if(response.body().getResponse().equals("already")){
                        Toast.makeText(EmailRegisterActivity.this, "This email is already exists, Please try another email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Users> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
            }

    }

    //////link code for text go to login page//////
    public void goToLogin(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(EmailRegisterActivity.this, EmailLoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        Animatoo.animateSlideRight(this);
        finish();
    }
    ///////end of code//////

    //////link code for back button go to main page//////
    public void goToMainPage(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(EmailRegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        Animatoo.animateSlideRight(this);
        finish();
    }
    //////end of code//////

}
```

This for easy code to see( just same code but i just cut the top and bottom code)

```
else {
            ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            dialog.setTitle("Registering...");
            dialog.setMessage("Please wait while we adding your credentials");
            dialog.show();
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

            Call<Users> call = apiInterface.performEmailRegistration(user_name,user_email,user_password);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<Users>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Users> call, Response<Users> response) {
                    if(response.body().getResponse().equals("ok")){
                        Toast.makeText(EmailRegisterActivity.this, "Your account has been created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }

                    else if(response.body().getResponse().equals("failed!")){
                        Toast.makeText(EmailRegisterActivity.this, "Something went wrong, Please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }

                    else if(response.body().getResponse().equals("already")){
                        Toast.makeText(EmailRegisterActivity.this, "This email is already exists, Please try another email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Users> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
            }

    }
```

Result just run dialog without dismiss dialog:

[image]

If you have any ideas or advice, I realy apreciate it.
Thanks

Comment: are you able to see toast to get confirmation of the to dismiss dialog code getting executed or not?

Comment: @TRKP What you means?

Comment: Is `Toast.makeText` appearing when you get any result on a given condition?

Comment: @TRKP I just try put dismiss dialog at dialog code without toast and if code(means I dont put if statment and toast) and it still not working

Comment: @TRKP its not appear.....but at another coding, its appear correctly

Comment: is your `Toast` called? Why `onFailure()` empty? Are you sure it is not go to 'onFailure()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tried your code, and it works perfectly.

Make sure you have an 'else' clause in your `onResponse`, and dismiss the dialog in `onFailure` as well

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<Users> call, Response<Users> response) {
    if(response.body().getResponse().equals("ok")){}
    else if(response.body().getResponse().equals("failed!")){}
    else if(response.body().getResponse().equals("already")){}
    else {
        Toast.makeText(EmailRegisterActivity.this, "Do'h, I forgot to put and 'else' clause", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}

@Override
public void onFailure(Call<Users> call, Throwable t) {
    Toast.makeText(EmailRegisterActivity.this, "Do'h, Failure :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    dialog.dismiss();
}
```